# Replace the last 3 zeroes of every line in a file with an incremental count like 001,002 and so on using unix shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a requirement where my file currently looks like below:

```
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000000    
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000000    
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000000
```

and the requirement is to replace the last columns zeroes with an incremental count .
i.e the output should look like below:

```
XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000001    
XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000002    
XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000003
```

.....................................000000010 and so on.
I am new to Unix and tried writing below code:

```
#!/bin/ksh

cd /test
find_list=`find Test_File_* -type f`
for file in $find_list
do
    string=$( cat $file |head -2) ;
    grep -E -i '00000000' Test_File_*
    typeset -Z9 number
    number=000
    echo $number
    ((number=++number))
    echo $number
    exit 0
done
```

But it gave me 2 new lines with the incremented count which is not my requirement.
Please help.

Comment: It looks like you want to do this for a series of files - in that case, should the count always start at `0` for each file?

Comment: **Q1**: `123456000` -> `123456001`?  **Q2**: if there are more than 1000 lines, which ending with `000`, what do you want to handle after `xxxxxx999`?

Answer (score 0):

If you know all lines end in '000' (and no trailing spaces!), you want to number the lines sequentially starting with '001', and you won't have more than 999 lines:

```
$ cat myfile
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000000
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000000
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000000

$ awk  '{printf "%s%03d\n", substr($0,1,length($0)-3), NR}'  myfile
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000001
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000002
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000003
```

- `substr($0,1,length($0)-3)` => strip off last 3 characters
- `printf "%s%03d\n"` - first position (%s) filled by the results of the `substr()` call; second position (%03d) is left zero padding of record's line number (NR); don't forget carriage return/linefeed (\n)
- if you have more than 999 lines then the `%03d` will actually generate 4/5/6-digit output (assuming 4/5/6-digit line numbers)

If some lines could have non-zeros in the last 3 positions, and you don't want to overwrite said digits, but you want to continue renumbering '000's (sequentially, starting with '001'):

```
$ cat myfile
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000000
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000456  <=== leave this one as is
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000000

# adding some white space for readability ...

$ awk  '
BEGIN  { mycount=1 }
/000$/ { printf "%s%03d\n", substr($0,1,length($0)-3), mycount; mycount++ ; next }
       { print }
' myfile

 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000001
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000456
 XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000002
```

- `mycount=1` - initialize our end-of-line counter
- `/000$/` - if line ends in '000' then issue the same printf as in the previous example, replacing the current line number (NR) with our counter (mycount)
- `mycount++ ; next` - increment our counter, skip to next line in file
- `{ print }` - if the pattern (/000$/) doesn't match, print the entire line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
#!/bin/ksh

typeset -RZ9 number

cd /test

for file in Test_File_*.txt; do
        if [[ -f $file ]]; then
                number=0
                #Doing backup of the original file. 
                mv $file $file".bck"
                while read line; do
                        newLine=$(sed 's|000000000|'$number'|g' <<< "$line")
                        print "$newLine" >> $file
                        ((number++))
        # You don't mention what to do after 999 so I put it back at 0                
                        if [[ $number -gt 999 ]]; then
                             number=0
                        fi
                done < $file".bck"
        fi
done
```

By the way, with ksh, you might want to use "print" instead of "echo". echo is an external binary while "print" is a built-in command.

Hope it could help

Answer (score 0):

This awk makes no assumptions about how many records are in the file:

```
awk '{$NF = sprintf("%0*d", length($NF), NR)} 1' file
```

but that destroys the field spacing:

```
XXXXXXX 290D 00 000000001
XXXXXXX 290D 00 000000002
XXXXXXX 290D 00 000000003
```

A little more complicated is to *replace* the last word with the desired number:

```
awk '{sub(/0+[[:blank:]]*$/, sprintf("%0*d", length($NF), NR))} 1' file
```

```
XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000001
XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000002
XXXXXXX    290D           00         000000003
```